# How to make even gaps between ticks on axis with recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I use reacharts to display changes of currencies rates in time. I have a currency value on Y axis and hour on X axis. I would like to have even gaps beetween ticks, but recharts doesn't do it and i don't know why. For example on Y axis i'd like to have 4 values, and 3 equal gaps beetwen them. Anyone can help me?

```
return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height='100%'>
        <LineChart data={getChartData()}>
          <Line type='linear' dataKey='sellValue' stroke={colors.chartBlue} dot={false} strokeWidth={2} />
          <Line type='linear' dataKey='buyValue' stroke={colors.chartRed} dot={false} strokeWidth={2} />
          <Line type='linear' dataKey='averageValue' stroke={colors.chartGray} dot={false} strokeWidth={2} />
          <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
          <XAxis dataKey='timestamp' tickMargin={5} minTickGap={30} />
          <YAxis padding={{ top: 10, bottom: 10 }} domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
```

[My sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtIoe.png)